# Import class from folder python

Tags: python, file, class, import, pycharm

Please don't immediately mark this as a duplicate question, because I have looked through loads of past questions with the same idea, but I don't understand any of the answers - they are bitty at best and involve making a file called **init**.py in the folder I think? I'm not sure.

So my specific problem is this: I am trying to write a program for blackjack. I have already created a class to create decks of cards in a separate file. I have everything in the same folder, called "classes". In this folder, there is:
- A file called __init.py (empty cause I don't know what it is supposed to do)
- A file called playingcardsclasses.py containing classes Card and Deck
- A file called blackjack.py which is where I am writing my main program. 
I am using Pycharm, and it throws out a Traceback immediately, but still runs the code like I want - so I don't know why it is breaking. 
The first line of my code is:

```
    from playingcardsclasses.py import Deck
```

The traceback says:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "(directory)/classes/blackjack.py", line 1, in 
    from playingcardsclasses.py import Deck
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'playingcardsclasses.py'; 'playingcardsclasses' is not a package

And then proceeds to run through the rest of my code happily, before finishing with a

Process finished with exit code 1

message - i.e. there is a problem here, hence the traceback.

Comment: For starters, remove the ``.py`` part when importing modules. Also, if you have already looked through other SO questions, it might be best to mention (link) them in your question and tell us what exactly didn't help you when you tried the given answers to those questions. That would help us not to give you answers that you've already tried.

Comment: ReadTheFineTutorial: [modules](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#modules)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the syntax of your `__init__.py` file in your `classes` directory is incorrect. It should be `__init__.py`, not `__init.py`.

The reason for an `__init__.py` file in a directory is to tell python that this directory should be treated as a package. I.e., other `.py` files can be imported from this directory. (see [here](https://pythontips.com/2013/07/28/what-is-__init__-py/))

In your case, as your `playingcardsclasses.py` file contains the two classes, `Card` and `Deck`, you can import them from another file. Let's say you're in another file in the same directory called `my_file.py`. If you wanted to import the  `Deck` class from `playingcardsclasses.py`, you would use:

```
from .playingcardsclasses import Deck
```

Note here that you should never use a trailing `.py` when importing, which is a mistake you made in your code block.

Edit: Also note the leading `.` in the import. This just specifies that the file `playingcardsclasses.py` is located in the same directory.

Comment: The __init rather than __init__ was a typo, but thanks! So is it okay if that file is empty? And do you just leave out the .py or is there something more complex?

Comment: Huh okay so apparently a double underscore represents bold in stack? That's kinda inconvenient. Also, my code still doesn't work - it says this:

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/charliefranklin/Google Drive/CS Charlie Franklin/Programs/CS work/Classes/__main__/Blackjack.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .playingcardsclasses import Deck
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.playingcardsclasses'; '__main__' is not a package

Comment: When it is in bold that should be surrounded by double underscores

Comment: Okay so I took out the preceding full stop and it works. So the line I have now is:

Comment: from playingcardsclasses import Deck

Comment: It is fine to leave `__init__.py` empty. You can and sometimes may need to populate it, but for this use case, it's okay to leave it empty. You can view it as a placeholder for python to classify this directory as a package.